# How to display textField in the Inputfield?

Tags: extjs, aem, crx

I have the following tag in some cq5 dialog.xml:

```
<text jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="label" name="./text"
 maxLength="150" xtype="textfield"  value ="This text has to be displayed in the input field"/>
```

Now when I call the dialog, I expect to see the following:
[image]

but the Inputfiled is empty :(

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `defaultValue` property:

```
<text
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="label"
    name="./text"
    maxLength="150"
    xtype="textfield"
    defaultValue="This text has to be displayed in the input field" />
```

More info can be found on the [CQ5 Widgets API](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.TextField) documentation.